# Collection of generic types

Tags: c#, generics, collections, interface

I have an object (form) which contains a collection (.Fields) which I want to contain instances of a generic class (FormField).

The FormField, simply, is defined as such:

```
public class FormField<T>
{
    private Form Form;
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Process()
    {
        // do something
    }

    public FormField(Form form, string name, T value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
        this.Form = form;
    }
}
```

This allows me to have FormField, FormField etc. and that part works great.
What I want is a collection of "Formfields" regardless of the type, but I am forced into defining a type (it seems) such as:

```
public class Form
{

    string Code { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
    int Year { get; set; }
    Guid ClientID { get; set; }

    ICollection<FormField<int>> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

What, I think, I want is an interface that allows me to abstract the type information and thus type the collection as instances of (for exxample) IFormField not FormField<>

But I can't see how to define this without strongly typing the collection in the interface...

Any help (including any alternative solutions!) would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks, Ben

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a non-generic interface or base class, which probably includes everything `FormField` does *except* the type-specific bits. Then you can have an `ICollection<IFormField>`. Obviously you won't be able to use this in a strongly-typed way, in terms of the type of field being used - but you can use all the non-type-specific bits of it (e.g. the name and the form).

Comment: thanks Jon, but if I understand you correctly then the interface would effectively have everything but the value property, which is a key element of the FormField..? 
Am I trying to use generics in the wrong way perhaps?

Comment: @Ben: Consider how you would try to *use* this collection. It could have a mixture of different form field types (int, string etc). How would you try to use the values from those form fields within `Form`? You won't know them at compile-time, or you'll be explicitly casting to the right type.

Comment: @Ben, you can declare a Value property in the IFormField interface, but you will have to declare it as Object. In the FormField<T> class, declare Value as T, and implement IFormField.Value explicitly.

Comment: ahh, of course. I'm looking at this from the wrong angle. Cheers Jon, much appreciated

Comment: @Thomas Levesque - Cheers Thomas, I did try with the collection defined as type Object and it was causing me some problems, but I think Jon has prompted me to re-evaluate what I'm trying to do, and how! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 13):

Here's some code to complete Jon's answer:

```
public interface IFormField
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    object Value { get; set; }
}

public class FormField<T> : IFormField
{
    private Form Form;
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Process()
    {
        // do something
    }

    public FormField(Form form, string name, T value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
        this.Form = form;
    }

    // Explicit implementation of IFormField.Value
    object IFormField.Value
    {
        get { return this.Value; }
        set { this.Value = (T)value; }
    }
}
```

And in your form:

```
ICollection<IFormField> Fields { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option (an alternative to [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3777085/590790)) is to apply the **[adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)**, which can be useful when:

- you are unable to modify the type, and can thus not define a base-type for it.
- or, there is a need to expose 'type-specific bits' (as Jon put it).

When you want to expose type-specific bits, you effectively [have to create a **non-generic wrapper**](https://whathecode.wordpress.com/2015/12/15/non-generic-wrapper-instead-of-base-class-or-interface/). A short example:

```
class NonGenericWrapper<T> : IAdaptor
{
    private readonly Adaptee<T> _adaptee;

    public NonGenericWrapper(Adaptee<T> adaptee)
    {
        _adaptee = adaptee;
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get { return _adaptee.Value; }
        set { _adaptee.Value = (T) value; }
    }
}
```

Implementing this non-generic behavior in a base-type would effectively break the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which is why I prefer the wrapper approach as [I also argue in my blog post](https://whathecode.wordpress.com/2015/12/15/non-generic-wrapper-instead-of-base-class-or-interface/).