# Different Generics T in the same collection

Tags: c#, generics

```
public abstract Column<T>
{
   private T Value {get;set;}    

   public abstract string Format();

}

public class DateColumn : Column<DateTime>
{
   public override string Format()
   {
      return Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
   }
}

public class NumberColumn : Column<decimal>
{
   public override string Format()
   {
      return Value.ToString();
   }
}
```

The problem I have is adding these into a generic collection. I know its possible but how can I store multiple types in a collection etc

```
IList<Column<?>> columns = new List<Column<?>()
```

I would really appreciate any advice on achieving this goal. The goal being having different column types stored in the same List. Its worth mentioning I am using NHibernate and the discriminator to load the appropriate object.Ultimately the Value needs to have the type of the class.

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I am confused about the point of this. Generics helps with type safety. Regardlesss, if you really wanted to do this, couldn't you populate your list with Column<object>?

Comment: No that wouldnt work, I have tried using a Column<object> I think the problem really lies with having Value defined through polymorphism and then being able to store that in a collection. I use the discriminator to load the different column types.

Comment: There are [a few](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3215402/590790) [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3777057/590790) of this question already. In addition to the 'base-type' solution [posted here by JaredPar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10606974/590790), I would like to propose [following the adapter pattern to create a non-generic wrapper to this purpose](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34417767/590790), so that the Liskov Substitution Principle is not broken.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In order to be stored in a `List<T>` together the columns must have a common base type.  The closest common base class of `DateColumn` and `NumberColumn` is `object`.  Neither derives from `Column<T>` but instead a specific and different instantiation of `Column<T>`.

One solution here is to introduce a non-generic `Column` type which `Column<T>` derives from and store that in the `List`

```
public abstract class Column { 
  public abstract object ValueUntyped { get; }
}

public abstract class Column<T> : Column {
  public T Value { get; set; }
  public override object ValueUntyped { get { return Value; } }
}

...

IList<Column> list = new List<Column>();
list.Add(new DateColumn());
list.Add(new NumberColumn());
```

Comment: You may also consider interface instead of base class.

Comment: Boxing happens here. T might be value type :(

Answer (score 3):

Generics are all about specifying type. If you want to use dynamic types, use classic `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: In this case I don't believe the OP wants dynamic typing but instead wants to take advantage of base types and polymorphic behavior

Comment: Yes you're correct @JaredPar I need to Parse the values and trying to guess what an object is is extremely difficult.

Comment: You're right, I +1ed your detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

It probably makes sense to derive from a non-generic `Column` class that wraps up as much of the non-generic common interface of a column... then to declare your list as `List<Column>`.

Comment: ...and what @JaredPar said...