# List of Raw generic type c#

Tags: c#, generics

I just started digging through C# being a java user. I run into a problem, declaring a list of generic raw type. Consider class `A<T>` and `B : A<String>`, `C : A<Int16>`. Now I want to declare something like `List<A> list`. I face a problem at this kind of declaration, getting a "*generic type argument requires 1 argument*". Is there any way I could do something like that? Or there are some other patterns in C# to use?

Comment: There are no raw generic types in C# and you must supply all the type parameters. How would you use such a type anyway? The best you could do would be `List<A<object>>` and then check the type dynamically.

Comment: Say more clearly what problem you are actually attempting to solve. It's hard to give suggestions for patterns when all we know is that you're trying to do something that the type system doesn't support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different Generics T in the same collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606935/different-generics-t-in-the-same-collection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a generic type you have to specify the type parameter. In this case to declare a `List` of `A` you have to specify `T`. For example:

```
List<A<int>> list = new List<A<int>>();
```

or seeing as `B` and `C` both derive from `A` and explicitly specify `T`, then you can have:

```
List<B> list = new List<B>();
List<C> list = new List<C>();
```

**UPDATE #1**

> Before using the following example I must admit I've not given it much
>   thought on just how useful/practical using a `List` of `dynamic` would
>   be or what issues may present themselves, but just thought I would
>   offer the suggestion.

```
public class A<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}  

List<A<dynamic>> list = new List<A<dynamic>>();

list.Add(new A<dynamic> { Value = "Hello World" });
list.Add(new A<dynamic> { Value = 100 });

foreach(A<dynamic> item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```