# Creating a generic list of composite generic subtypes in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have implemented the following hierachical data structure: **Tree<T> → Branch<T> → T**.

**UPDATE: Lots of people asked: Why don't you use object instead of <T> (or <dynamic> or whatever)? So I modified my question to state my "constraints". Here we go...**

Here are example `Tree`s:

```
*
├─Negative
│ ├─-2
├─0
│ ├─0
├─Positive
│ ├─2
│ ├─12
│ ├─2147483647

*
├─Spring
│ ├─Mar
│ ├─Apr
│ ├─May
├─Summer
│ ├─Jun
│ ├─Jul
│ ├─Aug
├─Fall
│ ├─Sep
│ ├─Oct
│ ├─Nov
├─Winter
│ ├─Dec
│ ├─Jan
│ ├─Feb
```

The implementation in C#:

```cs
public class Tree<T>
{
    public readonly List<Branch<T>> Branches = new List<Branch<T>>();
}

public class Branch<T>
{
    public readonly List<T> Leaves = new List<T>();
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class StringLeaf
{
    public StringLeaf(string value) { Label = value; }
    public string Label { get; private set; }
    public override string ToString() { return Label; }
}

public class PositiveIntLeaf
{
    private readonly int _value;
    public PositiveIntLeaf(int value) { _value = value; }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value < 0 ? "-" : _value.ToString(); }
    }
    public override string ToString() { return Value; }
}

public class IntTree : Tree<IntLeaf>
{
    private readonly Branch<IntLeaf> _negatives = new Branch<IntLeaf> { Name = "Negative" };
    private readonly Branch<IntLeaf> _zeros = new Branch<IntLeaf> { Name = "0" };
    private readonly Branch<IntLeaf> _positives = new Branch<IntLeaf> { Name = "Positive" };

    public IntTree()
    {
        Branches.AddRange(new []{
            _negatives,
            _zeros,
            _positives
        });
    }

    public void Add(int value)
    {
        if (value < 0) _negatives.Leaves.Add(new IntLeaf(value));
        else if (value > 0) _positives.Leaves.Add(new IntLeaf(value));
        else _zeros.Leaves.Add(new IntLeaf(value));
    }
}
```

Assuming I have different trees, **I'am incapable to put them into a list**:

```cs
IntTreeintTree = new IntTree();
intTree.Add(-2); intTree.Add(2); intTree.Add(0); intTree.Add(12); intTree.Add(int.MaxValue);
Tree<StringLeaf> months = new Tree<StringLeaf>{ Branches =
{
    new Branch<StringLeaf> { Name = "Spring", Leaves = { new StringLeaf( "Mar"),new StringLeaf("Apr") ,new StringLeaf("May")} },
    new Branch<StringLeaf> { Name = "Summer", Leaves = {  new StringLeaf( "Jun"),new StringLeaf("Jul") ,new StringLeaf("Aug")} },
    new Branch<StringLeaf> { Name = "Fall", Leaves = { new StringLeaf( "Sep"),new StringLeaf("Oct") ,new StringLeaf("Nov")} },
    new Branch<StringLeaf> { Name = "Winter", Leaves = { new StringLeaf( "Dec"),new StringLeaf("Jan") ,new StringLeaf("Feb")} }
}};

var list = new [] { intTree, months };
var currentTree = list[0];
// Work with the current tree:
var count = currentTree.Branches.Count;
Display(currentTree);
```

The errors is: *No best type found for implicitly-typed array*

**How can I get a list out of all this trees?**

I'd like to underline that I just want to put them in a list, maybe **iterate through it and access the current tree** and all **its branches** (e.g. to display their names). I don't care whether T is an object or an abstract base class! Assume that I just call `.ToString()`. The concrete type is just important for sub types like the `IntTree`.

Comment: Why use generics in this case when you seem to want to have different types in one collection? ArrayList could perhaps suffice?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Comment: It might be a meaningless comment, without knowing your constraints, but is there any point in keeping the classes generic if at the end of the day you're simply bundling them all together, loosing all the type-safety that generics provide?

Comment: read about covariance

Comment: @decPL Now there's a point in keeping the classes generic. I hope ...

Comment: @Marcel Only if you'll actually use the fact that they're generic. If you can't determine their type at compile time, the fact that they're generic gives you no benefit, while introducing additional complexity.

Answer (score 4):

You can't really. This is a problem known as covariance and contravariance in generics.
You can't stuff giraffes and tygers into a list of animals and hope that everything will be all right just because your collection is a list of animals.

So many articles written about this problem that I won't describe it to details. Just check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or google another articles.

Comment: +1 for identifying that covariance is at the root of the problem; -1 for suggesting that it can't be done.  The CLR has supported generics since .NET version 4.

Comment: @RobLyndon You sir, are mistaken. CLR has supported generics since .NET 2.0 along with covariance and contravariance but only for VB.NET. It was not until the release of .NET 4.0 that C# supports covariant IEnumerable and contravariant delegates.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant.  Shame I didn't say it.  I didn't know that VB supported covariance and contravariance back then.

Comment: @RobLyndon All right, so your -1 is for claiming that it can't be done no matter what? Because it can't be done as provided due to this limitations.

Comment: I haven't downvoted you -- just want to be clear on that.  When the OP asks "How can I get a list out of all this trees?", that is possible -- you just need to declare them as covariant interfaces.  It's not a perfect solution because covariance fails for value types, but if you're willing to pay the price of boxing your values, you can use covariance here.

Comment: Ok, I could have mentioned that. Never mind. Also, +1 for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

The one common collection will **know** only **one type of element**. Just like `List<int>` knows its element is `int`, `List<T>` knows its element is `T`.

So, if you know that all your Trees will be of the **same** type, but you don't know **which**, you have to abstract from that type:

```
class MyTreeHandler<T>
{
    public List<Tree<T>> myListOfTrees = new List<Tree<T>>();
}
```

and "here you go". Of course it will NOT work when trying to put heterogenous trees into that list, since `T` is **one type of an item**.

So, as collections like List know only one type of their item, before you can put heterogenous objects into one common list/collection, you have to find "common denominator" for all of them.

The simplest common denominator is an `object`, well, of course it is. So, the most dumb and always-working approach is:

```
List<object>
```

and you can put there any Trees of anything.

But, surely, you didn't want to hear it either. It's just to show you the common-denominator thing.

What common denominator your Trees have? As you presented - none. Of course, they are `Trees<T>` aka ``` Tree``1 ``` (one backtick should be, but I dont know how to write it here), but mind that except for a very few cases, you cannot use unparameterized type `Tree<>` in C#. And, you cannot use `Tree<T>` without defining the T to something. And after you define it, the `Tree<T1>` and `Tree<T2>` will be treated as two separate class hierarchies, unless T1==T2 or unless you use some `in/out` variance specifiers (like `IEnumerable<out>` does, hence `IEnumerable<Kangaroo>` **is castable** to a `IEnumerable<object>`). I assume you want a mixed-variance, so not an option. But if you want your tree to be input-only or output-only, use the co/contravariance specifiers at once!

So, let's leave generics and their variances. To provide a common-base understandable to C# language/compiler, you have to introduce something more .. basic.

Common `abstract` base other than `object`, some common `interface`. Whatever you deem least dirty.

When I **really** had to mix&store generics of different type, I usually introduced a simple dual interface:

```
public interface IMyThing //Typeless
{
    Type TypeParam {get;}

    object Operation(object a);
    object Property {get;set;}
}

public interface IMyThing<T> //TypeD
{
    T Operation(T a);
    T Property {get;set;}
}

public class MyThing<T> : IMyThing<T>, IMyThing
{
    public T Operation(T a) { .. }
    public T Property {get;set;}

    Type IMyThing.TypeParam {get{return typeof(T);}}
    object IMyThing.Operation(object a){return this.Operation((T)a);}
    object IMyThing.Property {get{return this.Property;}set{this.Property=(T)value;}}
}
```

Now I can cast every Thing to common IMyThing and store them as mixed, typeless `List<IMyThing>`. Thanks to explicit-interface-implementation, I will not see any "untyped" members unless I actually cast it, so other T-aware places will look as usual.

But, when I have to mix the types, I can now cast them to common typeless interface, and thanks to the interface I will still have access to the operations/properties. Assuming I will somehow guarantee that the args are castable to the correct T. But I can always check the TypeParam and handle it manually.

So, pure nuisance. As wrong as it feels, note that `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable` do exactly the same!

Cries for `dynamic`, but actually, without dynamic (i.e. have .Net 3.5 platform with no DLR?) there is little room for other solutions.

Comment: This is a well motivated, common implementation to this problem. However, [as I argue in my answer on a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34417767/590790), this breaks the Liskov Substition Principle. An alternate approach is creating a non-generic wrapper following the adapter pattern.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative would be to use the `dynamic` type. Try the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Tree<dynamic> intTree = CreateTree<dynamic>
        (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15);
    Tree<dynamic> charTree = CreateTree<dynamic>
        ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'C', 'E');
    Tree<dynamic> months = CreateTree<dynamic>
        ("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
    IEnumerable<Tree<object>> list = 
        new List<Tree<object>> { intTree, charTree, months };
}

private static Tree<T> CreateTree<T>(params T[] values)
{
    var t = new Tree<T>();
    var b = new Branch<T>();

    // some branching logic
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i % 4 == 3)
        {
            b.Leaves.Add(values[i]);
            t.Branches.Add(b);
            b = new Branch<T>();
        }
        else

            b.Leaves.Add(values[i]);
    }
    if (b.Leaves.Count != 0)
        t.Branches.Add(b);

    return t;
}
```

You could also create an extension method for your purpose:

```
public static Tree<dynamic> MakeDynamic<T>(this Tree<T> inputTree)
{
    var newTree = new Tree<dynamic>();
    for (int i = 0; i < inputTree.Branches.Count; i++)
    {
        var newBranch=new Branch<dynamic>();
        newTree.Branches.Add(newBranch);
        for (int j = 0; j < inputTree.Branches[i].Leaves.Count; j++)
        {
            dynamic d = inputTree.Branches[i].Leaves[j];
            inputTree.Branches[i].Leaves[j] = d;
        }
    }
    return newTree;
}
```

In this latter case, you might preserve your original types and have this sample usage:

```
IEnumerable<Tree<object>> list = new List<Tree<object>> { 
    intTree.MakeDynamic(), 
    charTree.MakeDynamic(), 
    months.MakeDynamic() 
};
```

Comment: @Marcel if every one of your trees becomes `Tree<dynamic>`, wouldn't it be simpler to drop the generic type from the class, and have just `Tree`?

Comment: @Moo-Juice That's anonymous types, not `dynamic`.  Entirely different.  No actual objects are of type `dynamic`.  You cannot new up a `dynamic`.  You can only have a variable of type `dynamic` meaning it can hold any actual object instance within it.

Comment: The use of `dynamic` is unnecessary here.  It doesn't add any value over and above the use of a common `Tree` base class.

Comment: One should use dynamic when a type-safe solution does not exist. This is not the case.