# Design Avoiding Having To Convert List<Derived> to List<Base>

Tags: c#

I'm developing an application.  For argument's sake, let's say the application represents zoo(s).  The data for each zoo is stored in a `List <Zoo>` type variable, where `Zoo` is defined as:

```
public class Zoo {
    List<Animal> animals;
    ...
}
```

`Animal` is defined as:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public virtual string Name {get; set;};

    ...
}
```

And various classes derive from `Animal`:

```
public class Dog {
    public int nLegs = 4;
    public string furColour= "White";
    public Dog() {
        Name = "Dog";
    }
    ...
}

public class Millipede {
    public int nLegs = int.maxValue;
    public Millipede() {
        Name = "Millipede";
    }
    ...
}

public class Goldfish {
    public string colour = "Red";
    public Goldfish() {
        Name = "Goldfish";
    }
    ...
}
```

Let's say we live in a crazy world where each `Zoo` can only have one type of `Animal` (but as many different instances of `Animal` as they want).  One particular `Zoo` really likes `Millipedes`:

```
List<Animal>.Add(new Millipede());
List<Animal>.Add(new Millipede());
List<Animal>.Add(new Millipede());
List<Animal>.Add(new Millipede());
```

Another `Zoo` really likes Goldfish:

```
List<Animal>.Add(new Goldfish());
List<Animal>.Add(new Goldfish());
List<Animal>.Add(new Goldfish());
List<Animal>.Add(new Goldfish());
```

In theory, the `Animal` class can be anything, and I have no way of knowing what different implementations will look like, but the specific `Zoo` class will.  Ideally, I'd like to work with `List<Dog>` or `List<Millipede>`, and not `List<Animal>`, so I can access specific properties/methods of the `Animal` subclass.  I've come across [Convert List<DerivedClass> to List<BaseClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass), which lists a few options and describes why casting `List<Animal>` to `List<Dog>` doesn't make much sense.  In my particular application, this conversion could be happening for many lists with a large number of items each (1000s), multiple times per second per list, so it's not feasible for me to do a conversion each time.

For an example like the above, what is the best way to organise the class structure, so that this problem can be avoided altogether?

Comment: It's _design_ not _"architecture"_

Comment: Make `Zoo` generic? e.g.: `Zoo<T> where T: Animal`?

Comment: Thanks @MickyD, title updated.

Comment: @UnholySheep I've had a look at the answer below which provides the same solution, and that does indeed solve the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you need:

```
public class Zoo<T> where T : Animal
{
    public List<T> animals = new List<T>();
}

public abstract class Animal
{
    public virtual string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public int nLegs = 4;
    public string furColour= "White";
    public Dog()
    {
        Name = "Dog";
    }
}

public class Millipede : Animal
{
    public int nLegs = int.MaxValue;
    public Millipede()
    {
        Name = "Millipede";
    }
}

public class Goldfish : Animal
{
    public string colour = "Red";
    public Goldfish()
    {
        Name = "Goldfish";
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
var zoo = new Zoo<Dog>();
zoo.animals.Add(new Dog());
zoo.animals.Add(new Dog());
zoo.animals.Add(new Dog());
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your best bet would be to try and track down the common behavior of every type of object you are planning to work with. This might be pretty easy in the case of a collection of animals (based on your example), but almost impossible if the objects differ very much from one to another (cars, computer peripherals, construction materials and food).

If you manage to find similarities in **behavior** between them, then your best bet would be using a general interface which should implemented by every object you are planning to use.

Based on your example, you could add something like this:

```
public enum AnimalGroupEnum
{
    Amphibian,
    Bird,
    Fish,
    Invertebrate,
    Mammal,
    Reptile,
}
```

Along with an interface:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    AnimalGroupEnum AnimalGroup { get; }
}
```

Then your `Zoo` class becomes:

```
public class Zoo 
{
    List<IAnimal> Animals
}
```

And all animals defined (`Dog`, `Millipede` or `Goldfish`) should implement this interface to be able to add it to the `Animals` collection. But doing this you would only have access to the `AnimalGroup` property when you go over the collection. Of course, this interface could contain other things which you need from your objects.

Hopefully this sheds some light over your question.

Comment: What does `AnimalGroupEnum` have to do with anything that the OP asked?

Comment: @Enigmativity It has something to do with the architecture he's talking about. It would have been pretty weird to add `NumberOfLegs` for a class called `GoldFish`. I wanted to give an example for something which can be made common for each type of object. Also, your example (since I can only comment here) makes collecting everything under the same collection a bit difficult. It's possible, as can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215402/collection-of-generic-types