# trying to pass generic id's to class constructor

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, generics

I have below class `LibrarySourceTableInput` and having structure like as this

```
public class LibrarySourceTableInput<T> where T: ISourceOfData
{      
    public LibrarySourceTableInput(List<T> libraries, string mappedLibrarySource)
    {
        this.LibrarySourceRowInputs = libraries?.Select(l => new LibrarySourceRowInput()
            {
                LibrarySourceId = l.Id,
                SourceOfDataId = l.SourceOfData.Id
            }).ToList() ?? new(),
         this.MappedLibrarySource = mappedLibrarySource;
    }
    public List<LibrarySourceRowInput> LibrarySourceRowInputs { get; set; }
    public string MappedLibrarySource { get; set; }
}
```

and then the interface `ISourceOfData` structure looks like as this below

```
public interface ISourceOfData : IIdentity
{
    public new Guid Id { get; set; }
    public CodeStandardGuideline SourceOfData { get; set; }
}
```

And i am calling above class constructor in other place like as this

```
var mechanicalData = spaceTypeObject.TargetObject.MechanicalData;                           
 var librarySourceTableInputs = new List<LibrarySourceTableInput<ISourceOfData>>
 {
     new LibrarySourceTableInput<ISourceOfData>(mechanicalData?.Environments, mappedLibrarySource), // I am getting conversion error here 
     new LibrarySourceTableInput<ISourceOfData>(mechanicalData?.AirflowsA621 , mappedLibrarySource)
     .......
     .......
 }
```

and the structure for mechanicaldata.environments is looks like this

```
public class MechanicalData
{
    public List<LibraryEnvironment> Environments { get; set; }
    public List<LibraryA621> AirflowsA621 { get; set; }
    .......
}
```

and then last one libraryEnvironment class is looks like this

```
 public class LibraryEnvironment : ISourceOfData
 {
    public virtual CodeStandardGuideline SourceOfData { get; set; }
    .....
    ......
    public Guid Id {get; set;}     
 }
```

I have got the below error at this line `new LibrarySourceTableInput<ISourceOfData>(mechanicalData?.Environments, mappedLibrarySource)`

and the error is `Cannot convert from Generic.List<LibraryEnvironment>  to Generic.List<IsourceOfData>`

Could any one please let me know or any idea on how to send that generic list to that class constructor, Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you absolutely must work with a generic class, you might want to take a look at this question: [Collection of generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3215402)

Comment: never mind  i figured out that just need to cast to corresponding interface

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying the interface ISourceOfData (your class already knows the type will have that interface), specify the actual class:

```
var librarySourceTableInputs = new List<LibrarySourceTableInput<LibraryEnvironment>>
{
    new LibrarySourceTableInput<LibraryEnvironment>(mechanicalData?.Environments, mappedLibrarySource),
     .......
     .......
}
```

Comment: I am passing different types to it in that i need to define `IsourceOfData` and i updated my question